# Drying Fir Rounds for Outdoor Table

Tags: outdoor, wood-drying

I have a couple rounds cut off a 42 inch (107 cm) diameter Douglas Fir log that I'd like to turn into tables for use outdoors on a covered porch.  The rounds are about 4 inches (10 cm) thick.  I'm wondering how long they should air dry before making the tables.  I plan to varnish both top and bottom.  I know a general rule of thumb is a year per inch of thickness, but I'm thinking these should dry much faster than that since nearly all the exposed surface is end grain.

The tree was cut two years ago, but the log was just cut into rounds a few days ago - my moisture meter said about 30% when cut. Most of the bark is still on but some has come off. I will remove it all. I see one very narrow crack now but assume it will grow. I'm not in a great hurry but planning to air dry it in my garage and wanting to know how long I should expect it to take. Not sure what the money reference is but I'm not going to buy a drying kiln - air drying is fine.

Any experience or guidance?

Comment: I assume you are aware that your log slices are likely to split from perimeter to center at one or more places as it dries.  This is because the log shrinks twice as much along the growth rings as it does across them putting great force at the perimeter for wood to split due to the differential forces.

Comment: @Ashlar Yes, I recognize that and assume that part of the process will be to put in some bowties across cracks to help keep them together.

Comment: Hi, how much time do you have? How much money do you have? When did you cut? Was tree just felled or was the log older? Have any cracks already? Will you leave on bark?

Comment: You're in a bit of luck with the tree not being cut down just in the last week or so — the worst time to ask this sort of question is a couple of days after rounds were sawn from a tree that was just felled..... and you wouldn't believe how common that is LOL The wood has had quite a long time to do some of the drying in log form which would largely protect from the kind of cracking that rounds are so known for. *"I'm thinking these should dry much faster"* Yes, and that's a problem. You want to slow that down as much as you can if the plan is to just air dry.